# Can't get value which is changed inside Runnable

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I have a code like this:

```
time = 5;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               if(time == 0)
                   time = 0;
               else {
                   time --;
               }
               handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
           }
        };
```

My application contains a button which needs to collect value of the 'time' but the problem is when I click the button, value of the 'time' is always 5 no matter when I click the button. I tested it and 'time' really decreases by one but I can't get that value.

How can I get real value of the 'time' variable after I click a button?

Comment: time is a field variable or local?

Comment: It's a global variable. I just put it there so I don't paste whole code.

Comment: You can put it in a bundle, pass the bundle to a message, and send a message to your handler. You can then receive the message in your handler and pull the data out of the bundle.

Comment: where you try to read it?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno, inside button onClickListener. Both Runnable and onClickListener are inside my fragment's onCreateView.

Comment: @zgc7009, Thank you but I don't really understand what I need to do. How can I store that value which I change inside Handler?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `time` as `volatile`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread for your handler to handle. Have the thread run in the background, but have it pass it's information back to your handler via a message bundle. Something like this

```
private class HandlerThread extends Thread{
    private Handler handler;


    public HandlerThread(Handler uiHandler){
        handler = uiHandler;
    }

    public void run(){
        int time = 5;
        Bundle b;

        for(int i = 0; i < time; i++){
            b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("time_key", time);
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
            message.setData(b);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }                    
    }
}
```

And then have your handler handle the message

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        Bundle b;
        b = msg.getData();

        mainUiTime = b.getInt("time_key",0))
    }
};
```

You can start your background thread like this

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(handler);
handlerThread.start();
```

As a note, you will also need to figure out a way of canceling your thread once it is done running. This is usually done by creating a boolean variable, something like keepRunning, and put it in your run() method as a while loop; while(keepRunning). Then in your mainUi change the variable to false when you are out of buttons so that it essentially terminates the running portion of the thread.